# How do you find table intersections in PostgREST clients?

Tags: postgresql, supabase, postgrest, supabase-database

Simple question from a rookie to PostgREST - is there an intersect function for the equivalent below PSQL query?

```
select a from table1 
intersect
select a from table2;
```

I read through the documentation https://postgrest.org/en/stable/ and didn't see any commands.

If relevant, I'm using Supabase clients for postgREST right now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view and then query the view via PostgREST.